# Functions involving codomains

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:** Consider the possible $f: [7]\to[9]$

a) How many have $f(i) $even , for all *i*?
b) How many have rng(*f*) = {5,6}

As far problem a goes, I've only gotten to the answer = 4^7. However I'm not sure that that is the answer and if so, I don't know why.

As for problem b, I'm not even sure what rng means nor how it relates to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed $4^7$ functions from $[7]$ to $[9]$ such that $f(i)$ is even for each $i\in[7]$. The reason is that there are $4$ even integers in $[9]$, $2,4,6$, and $8$. Thus, you’re really counting the functions from $[7]$ to the $4$-element set $\{2,4,6,8\}$. For each $i\in[7]$ you can let $f(i)$ be any of these $4$ even integers, and you make such a $4$-way choice for each of the $7$ elements of $[7]$. Thus, you make a $4$-way choice $7$ times, something that can be done in $4^7$ ways (by the multiplication principle).

In (b) $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is the *range* of the function $f$, i.e., the set of all ‘outputs’ of $f$, $\{f(1),\ldots,f(7)\}$. You’re asked to count the functions from $[7]$ to $[9]$ that have the following properties:

1. $f(i)$ is either $5$ or $6$ for each $i\in[7]$;
2. there is at least one $i\in[7]$ such that $f(i)=5$; and
3. there is at least one $i\in[7]$ such that $f(i)=6$.

The easiest approach is to notice that if you know which $i\in[7]$ are such that $f(i)=5$, then you know all of $f$: all of the other members of $[7]$ must be sent to $6$ by $f$. For instance, if I know that the numbers sent to $5$ by $f$ are $1$ and $3$, then I know that $2,4,5,6$, and $7$ must be sent to $6$ by $f$. Each of the desired functions $f$ is completely determined by the set $$S_f=f^{-1}[\{5\}]=\{i\in[7]:f(i)=5\}\;.$$

Thus, to count the desired functions we need only count the possible sets $S_f\subseteq[7]$. Each of them must be non-empty, since there has to be at least one $i\in[7]$ such that $f(i)=5$, and that $i$ is in $S_f$. And none of them can be all of $[7]$, since there has to be at least one $i\in[7]$ such that $f(i)=6$, and that $i$ is not in $S_f$. You know how many subsets $[7]$ has, and you know how many of them *can’t* be $S_f$; the difference is the number of possible sets $S_f$ and therefore the number of functions of the desired type.

Comment: What if I'm asked: How many have f(1) != 5, and are one-to-one?

Comment: @Bobobobobobobo: Use the multiplication principle and imagine constructing $f$ one value at a time. There are $8$ possible choices for $f(1)$. Once you’ve chosen $f(1)$, there are still $8$ possible choices for $f(2)$: anything in $[9]$ except $f(1)$. Then there are $7$ choices for $f(3): anything in $[9]$ except $f(1)$ and $f(2)$. And so on.